# How to test that my Django email view can catch a BadHeaderError?

Tags: django, email

I have a Django view with an email form.  It allows the user to type a subject and message, and send that as an email to the site admin.  I would like to write a unit test that ensures that this view can catch a [BadHeaderError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/email/#preventing-header-injection).

```
subject = contact_form.cleaned_data['subject']
message = contact_form.cleaned_data['message']
try:
    mail_admins(
        subject=subject,
        message=message,
    )
except BadHeaderError:
    # I want to test this case.
    messages.error(request, "Sorry, the email could not be sent. An invalid header was found.")
else:
    messages.success(request, "Your email was sent to the admins.")
```

How do I trigger a BadHeaderError in a unit test?

I know the canonical example of header injection is having a newline character in the subject.  However, I wrote a unit test that fills out this form with a newline character in the subject, and it didn't trigger the invalid header message.

```
# This didn't trigger the invalid header message. So how do I do it?
response = self.client.post(reverse('contact_us'), dict(
    subject="Subject goes here\ncc:spamvictim@example.com",
    message="Message goes here",
))
```

**Edit:**

[Hassek's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12549859/859858) of using Mocker is an avenue of approach I hadn't originally considered, and will work for my purpose here.  However, I'm curious as to what actually triggers a BadHeaderError in the mail functions - what kind of special character is needed in the subject, if a newline doesn't do it?  Or is there another way to trigger the BadHeaderError?  I don't know too much about web security, so I'd like to learn these things.

**Edit 2:**

I was using Django 1.3.0.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet is from Django's own tests; this is how they test that this error is raised

```
def test_header_injection(self):
    email = EmailMessage('Subject\nInjection Test', 'Content', 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'])
    self.assertRaises(BadHeaderError, email.message)
```

Comment: Good call, checking Django's own tests would be the smart thing to do here. Thanks for that. Looks like the newline is supposed to trigger the error then, but of course, my example has a newline too. I think I know what's going on now; it's explained in this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510969/why-does-this-django-test-pass So their answer should essentially be the accepted answer here.

Comment: This was in Django 1.7's tests so I can understand why it didn't work in your case. But I'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [mocker](http://labix.org/mocker) on the mail_admins function to raise the BadHeaderError when called. it would be something like this:

```
from mocker import Mocker, KWARGS

mocker = Mocker()
raise_error = mocker.replace('COMPLETE_PATH_TO_mail_admins_FUNCTION')  
#  i.e django.contrib.emails.mail_admins

raise_error(KWARGS)
mocker.raise(BadHeaderException)
```

haven't test this yet but it should help you out :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I hadn't considered this sort of approach at all.  It certainly sounds like Mocker will work for my purpose here, and could be a useful tool in the future.  However, I am actually curious about how to legitimately trigger the BadHeaderError case in the Django mail functions (what kind of special character, or whatever else is needed).  So if someone can provide an answer for that, then I'll accept that answer; otherwise, I'll accept your answer after a few days.  Either way, +1.