# Why does this Django test pass?

Tags: django, unit-testing

Calling the send_mail function independently will cause a BadHeaderError exception due to the newline in the subject.

I expect this test_newline_causes_exception to fail as well, but it does not. This is in Django 1.3. Any ideas?

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils import unittest

class EmailTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_newline_causes_exception(self):
        send_mail('Header\nInjection', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
                  ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

**EDIT:** This new test shows that the header checking code (django.core.mail.message.forbid_multi_line_headers) is not called when send_mail is used in tests.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError, outbox
from django.utils import unittest

class EmailTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_newline_in_subject_should_raise_exception(self):

        try:
            send_mail('Subject\nhere', 'Here is the message.',
                      'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
        except BadHeaderError:
            raise Exception

        self.assertEqual(len(outbox), 1)

        self.assertEqual(outbox[0].subject, 'Subject here')
```

Result:

```
AssertionError: 'Subject\nhere' != 'Subject here'
```

Comment: does it throw exception in django shell?

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev Yes.

Comment: Django replaces the normal email backend with testing one during testing phase. This can be a reason. Please check if there is smth in django.core.mail.outbox, or, in other words, if the message was actually sent. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#e-mail-services.

Comment: That could be the reason. The message is getting through somehow. See my edit to code.

Comment: Found a related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549175/how-to-test-that-my-django-email-view-can-catch-a-badheadererror

Comment: You are writing a test case in django, to test django's own functionality. This doesn't seem right. You should be testing your own code. Unless this is an exercise in understanding django's testing framework, it has no other use.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The actual test I need is to ensure that a custom function that calls send_mail replaces newlines. Instead of posting my test and function here I posted a simplified version of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this issue has been fixed in Django 1.5. The testing email backend (locmem.py) now performs the same header sanitization as the standard backends.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18861

https://github.com/django/django/commit/8599f64e54adfb32ee6550ed7a6ec9944034d978

**EDIT**

I found a workaround for testing header validation in Django versions <1.5.

Use the get_connection method to load the console backend which performs the same validations as the production backend.

Thanks to Alexander Afanasiev for pointing me in the right direction.

```
connection = get_connection('django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend')
send_mail('Subject\nhere',
          'Here is the message.',
          'from@example.com',
          ['to@example.com'],
          fail_silently=False,
          connection=connection)
```

Comment: So, for django<1.5 a workaround is to mock `django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend.send_messages` method and call `message.message()` for every message, right? Then I think it should be accepted as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You're not really testing anything. Testing would imply checking if the `BadHeaderError` has been raised or not. The test would fail if an assert test is false. You could do something like this -

```
def test_newline_causes_exception(self)
    error_occured = False
    try:
        send_mail('Header\nInjection', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
                  ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
    except BadHeaderError:
        error_occured = True

    self.assertTrue(error_ocurred)
```

I haven't tested it. But it should work.

PS: `from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError`

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you are saying, but the test I wrote should still fail, right?  Just as it would fail if I included a line with 'raise Exception'.

Comment: Maybe, I don't know for sure how you are implementing it. There might be a lot of other conditions that can affect it(e.g. mail delivery delay etc). I just know that if you want to check if `BadHeaderError` is being raised, you should check that and not something other way around.